# Change Greenland's continent using rworldmap

Tags: r

I am using the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20146809/how-can-i-plot-a-continents-map-with-r) and `exactextractr::exact_extract` to find the average of my raster file by continent.  I particularly like the `rworldmap` option because I am looking to analyze by North America/Eurasia (rather than North America/Europe/Asia),  and `rworldmap` combines Europe and Asia into Eurasia. However, I'd like Greenland to be part of North America and not Eurasia.  How can I change its continent?

```
library(exactextractr)
library(raster)
library(sf)
library(rworldmap)
library(rgeos)
library(maptools)
library(cleangeo) 

sPDF <- getMap()
#### I assume the changing continent part would go here
sPDF <- clgeo_Clean(sPDF)  ## Needed to fix up some non-closed polygons 
cont <-
  sapply(levels(sPDF$continent),
         FUN = function(i) {
           ## Merge polygons within a continent
           poly <- gUnionCascaded(subset(sPDF, continent==i))
           ## Give each polygon a unique ID
           poly <- spChFIDs(poly, i)
           ## Make SPDF from SpatialPolygons object
           SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(poly,
                                    data.frame(continent=i, row.names=i))
         },
         USE.NAMES=TRUE)
cont <- Reduce(spRbind, cont)
noant <- cont[cont$continent!="Antarctica",] # antarctica breaks spTransform
myraster<-raster('filepath')    
trans <-spTransform(noant,crs(myraster))
nam_eur<- st_as_sf(trans)
raster_mean<-exact_extract(myraster,nam_eur,'mean')


plot(cont, col=heat.colors(nrow(cont)))
```

shows Greenland as part of Eurasia:
[image]

Comment: Iceland and Denmark are European countries so changing the continent might mess up something else.

Comment: Politically, Greenland is European, but geologically it is North American. Hence, the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is you can put Greenland in the continent it belongs to. The continent North America also includes Central America, the Caribbean and Mexico; so I fixed that too.

```
w <- rworldmap::getMap()
w$continent[w$ADMIN == "Greenland"] <- "North America"
w$continent[w$AVOIDname %in% c("Caribbean", "Central America", "Mexico")] <- "North America"

w <- cleangeo::clgeo_Clean(w) 
a <- raster::aggregate(w, "continent")
plot(a, col=rainbow(7))
```